# Merging Dictionary to Dataframe where both dictionary values are scalar

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
my_dict = {0:45,1:89.9,2:7.65}
```

I wanna merge it to my DataFrame, where my Dataframe looks like this:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'score':[11.7,99.8,83.5],'color':['pink','red','green']})
```

[image]

I would like my final merged dataframe to look like this:

```
 my_df_final = pd.DataFrame({'score':[11.7,99.8,83.5],'color':['pink','red','green'], dict_values:[45,89.9,7.56]})
```

[image]

`pd.DataFrame(caption_count_dict`)
But when I try to create a dataframe from my dictionary, I get the message that "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index". I am not able to figure out how to supply the index or how to merge this dictionary with my dataframe as a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_df['dict_values'] = pd.Series(my_dict)
```

Output

```
   score  color  dict_values
0   11.7   pink        45.00
1   99.8    red        89.90
2   83.5  green         7.65
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pandas.Series` to convert before concat:

```
my_df["dict_values"] = pd.Series(my_dict)
print(my_df)
```

Output:

```
   score  color  dict_values
0   11.7   pink        45.00
1   99.8    red        89.90
2   83.5  green         7.65
```